# How to get the height of an image and apply that height to a div?

Tags: jquery, css

I am building a mobile web app and I'm using jquerytools slider on it.

i want te slider to show (in proper ratio) across all mobile devices so width of the images is 100% and height is auto in css. However as all the elements are floated and jquerytools slider requires the position be set to absolute, the containing div (#header) doesn't stretch to fit the content.

I am trying to use jquery to get the height of the height of the img and apply that height to the header.... however I am having no luck.

CSS:

```
    #header{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 20;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px white; */
    overflow: auto;
    }

.scrollable {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/* box-shadow: 0 0 20px purple; */
/*  height:198px; */
z-index: 20;
overflow: auto;
}


.scrollable .items {
/* this cannot be too large */
width:1000%;
position:absolute;
clear:both;
/* box-shadow: 0 0 30px green; */

}

.items div {
float:left;
width:10%;
height:100%;

}

/* single scrollable item */
.scrollable img {
    /* float:left; */
    width:100%;
   height: auto;
 /*    height:198px; */
}

/* active item */
.scrollable .active {
    border:2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    cursor:default;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id=header><!-- root element for scrollable -->
<div class="scrollable" id="scrollable">

  <!-- root element for the items -->
  <div class="items">


    <div>
      <img src="img/img2.jpg" />
    </div>


    <div>
       <img src="img/img1.jpg" />
    </div>


    <div>
     <img src="img/img3.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div>
     <img src="img/img4.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div>
     <img src="img/img6.jpg" />
    </div>

</div><!-- items -->

</div><!-- scrollable -->

</div><!-- header -->
```

UPDATED JQUERY

```
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img.scrollable").each(function() {
            $('#header').css("height",$(this).innerHeight());
        });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: yeah sorry i just noticed that. I have just gone back over the questions I have asked on here and ticked the relevant answers, where there was one. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this jquery function: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: thanks, but I have been playing with that a lot. I will update my original question with the jquery I am using just now.